# A word for 'here all the time'?

Tags: single-word-requests, poetic

So I'm doing an assignment where I have to analyse a music piece. In this one piece at the start theres a couple of instruments who play a phrase all together. They keep playing this same phrase throughout the piece and never change, very subtle but these instruments help the main melody.

They're god-like, always here and never leaves. How would you describe that state in one word?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest the word **Omnipresent.** It will suit your need.

Oxford Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnipresent

> (of God) present everywhere at the same time.

From Vocabulary.com  https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/omnipresent

> Omnipresent describes something that's everywhere at once, like a deity. If your parents are constantly monitoring what you do, you may feel like they're omnipresent.

You can use it in your sentence: They're god-like, ***omnipresent***.